# Uniform Boundedness of Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $c_{0}=\{(x_{i})_{i\geq 1} | x_{i}\in\mathbb{K}\text{ and } \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}x_{i}=0\}$. Suppose $y_{i}\in\mathbb{K}$, $i=1,2,\ldots$, such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}y_{i},
\end{align}
converges $\forall (x_{i})_{i\geq 1}\in c_{o}$. Use Uniform Boundedness to show that $(y_{i})_{i\geq 1}\in\ell^{1}$. ($\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)

The idea is to construct a family of operators $(T_{n})$ such that the end result by the Uniform Boundedness Principle is $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|T_{n}|<\infty\implies\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|y_{i}|<\infty$.

So, I tried defining $T_{n}:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_{i}|$ such that $T_{n}x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_{i}|x_{i}$. However,
\begin{align}
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|T_{n}x|=\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|y_{i}|x_{i}\bigg|,
\end{align}
is not bounded by the assumptions of the question.

So then I proceeded to try $T_{n}:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}$ such that $T_{n}x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{i}$. In this case,
\begin{align}
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|T_{n}x|=\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}y_{i}x_{i}\bigg|<\infty,
\end{align}
by the assumption,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}y_{i}<\infty.
\end{align}
This of course implies that we satisfy the conditions of the Uniform Boundedness Principle, which gives,
\begin{align}
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|T_{n}|=\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}y_{i}\bigg|<\infty.
\end{align}
However this does not imply that,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|y_{i}|<\infty,
\end{align}
and in fact I cannot extract the result from this at all.

Can anyone give some guidance on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_ky_k$. Then $T_n$ is a linear functional on $c_0$. Also $|T_nx|\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |y_k|M$ where $M=\sup_k|x_k|$ (the norm of $x$ in $c_0$). Hence $T_n$ is a continuous linear functional on $c_0)$ with $\|T_n\| \leq  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |y_k|$. Let us find the exact value of $\|T_n\|$. For this take $x_k=\frac {|y_k|} {y_k}$ if $1\leq k \leq n$ and $y_k \neq 0$ and $0$ if $1\leq k \leq n$ with $y_k=0$. Also let $x_k=0$ for all $k>n$. Then $\|x\|=1$ and  $T_nx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |y_k|$. Thus $\|T_n\|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |y_k|$. The hypothesis also tells us that $\{T_nx\}$ is a bounded sequence for a given $x \in c_0$. Now Uniform Boundedness Principle tells us that $\|T_n\|$ is a bounded sequence which means $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |y_k|<\infty$.

Comment: By constructing a particular sequence $(x_{i})$ do we not lose generality?

Comment: @Jack If you want to prove that the norm of linear map $T$ is greater than or equal to some number $C$ it is enough to find one unit vector $x$ such that $\|Tx\| \geq C$ because  $\|T\| =\sup \{\|Tx\|:\|x\| =1\}$.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for helping.